# Interaction between for loops with clock function?

Tags: c++, x86

Can someone explain me the exact interaction in context of delay between the two for loops with clock function. How does for1 interact with for2 on the cout statement(30 on 640000000)?

```
start=clock();
cout<<endl<<start<<endl;
for(delay=0; delay<30; delay++)
    for(i=0; i<640000000; i++);

end=clock();
cout<<end<<endl;
cout<<"Num of ticks for non reg-loop: ";
cout<<end-start<<'\n';
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't understand how does loop complete with 30*640000000 iterations which is impossible for 32bit compiler to handle with?

Comment: Integer limitation and cout's are processed to fast for 30*640000000 iterations... How delay actually works (I'm a C++ beginner btw). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a decent optimizer will see that the loop is a no-op and optimize it out completely, so there will be almost no difference between start and end.

If it's not optimized out, the two loops are simply working around the fact that 30*640000000 is bigger than could be stored in a 32-bit integer. It runs the inner 640000000 loop 30 times to attempt to magnify the delay.

EDIT:
So for each of 30 times (using variable `delay`), it creates another loop (using variable `i`) starting at 0. It then increments `i` 640000000 times, each increment taking a small fraction of time (if not optimized away). Then the inner loop completes, `delay` is increased by 1, and the inner loop starts over at 0 again.

EDIT2:
If you're just trying to add a delay, have you considered using `sleep` or `usleep` or the corresponding Windows function(s) rather than trying to implement a sleep by iteration?

Comment: One more thing Mark, I don't understand how does inner for complete its 64000000 iterations so fast (i=0; i<640000000; i++ ). Is it skipped somehow or what?

Comment: @learningtolive Exactly. Since there isn't any actual work inside the loop the compiler will remove the entire loop and not do any incrementing at all.